# How to insert spark structured streaming DataFrame to Hive external table/location?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, spark-structured-streaming

One query on spark structured streaming integration with HIVE table.

I have tried to do some examples of spark structured streaming.

here is my example

```scala
 val spark =SparkSession.builder().appName("StatsAnalyzer")
     .enableHiveSupport()
     .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
     .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
     .config("spark.sql.streaming.checkpointLocation", "hdfs://pp/apps/hive/warehouse/ab.db")
     .getOrCreate()

 // Register the dataframe as a Hive table

 val userSchema = new StructType().add("name", "string").add("age", "integer")
 val csvDF = spark.readStream.option("sep", ",").schema(userSchema).csv("file:///home/su/testdelta") 
 csvDF.createOrReplaceTempView("updates")
 val query= spark.sql("insert into table_abcd select * from updates")

 query.writeStream.start()
```

As you can see in the last step while  writing data-frame to hdfs location, , the data is not getting inserted into the exciting directory (my existing directory having some old data partitioned by "age").

I am getting

> spark.sql.AnalysisException : queries with streaming source must be executed with writeStream start()

Can you help why i am not able to insert data in to existing directory in hdfs location ? or is there any other way that i can do "insert into " operation on hive table ?

Looking for a solution

Comment: Ok my issue is not readStream...how to insert that data into existing hive table? I need to do insert into operation

Comment: Yes am getting spark.sql.AnalysisException : queries with streaming source must be executed with writeStream start()

Comment: my question is how to do transformations like JOIN ?

Comment: i want to join stream data from kafka or csv and static data from HIVE... hafter writting everything to hive doesn't work as i need to perform all operations in streaming manner....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185895/discussion-between-bigd-and-cricket-007).

Comment: If you want to "watch" for file appending operations, use something like Fluentbit or Filebeat. Then you can stream CSV data to a Spark socket server, or Kafka. From there, you can write to HDFS/Hive

Answer (score 9):

Spark Structured Streaming does not support writing the result of a streaming query to a Hive table.

```
scala> println(spark.version)
2.4.0

val sq = spark.readStream.format("rate").load
scala> :type sq
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

scala> assert(sq.isStreaming)

scala> sq.writeStream.format("hive").start
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Hive data source can only be used with tables, you can not write files of Hive data source directly.;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.start(DataStreamWriter.scala:246)
  ... 49 elided
```

If a target system (aka *sink*) is not supported you could use use [foreach and foreachBatch operations](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach-and-foreachbatch) (highlighting mine):

> The `foreach` and `foreachBatch` operations allow you to apply **arbitrary operations and writing logic on the output of a streaming query**. They have slightly different use cases - while `foreach` allows custom write logic on every row, `foreachBatch` allows arbitrary operations and custom logic on the output of each micro-batch.

I think `foreachBatch` is your best bet.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
sq.writeStream.foreachBatch { case (ds: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
  // do whatever you want with your input DataFrame
  // incl. writing to Hive
  // I simply decided to print out the rows to the console
  ds.show
}.start
```

---

There is also [Apache Hive Warehouse Connector](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/latest/integrating-hive/content/hive_hivewarehouseconnector_for_handling_apache_spark_data.html) that I've never worked with but seems like it may be of some help.

Comment: Hello.. One more query... Is it possible to stream a file, lets say csv file to spark streaming? If i append any line to that file then that should captures by spark streaming..is it possible? Adding files to directory and streaming is possible... File streaming is possible in spark?

Comment: @BigD No it's not possible to append lines to a CSV file and "catch" the updates. Only new files are going to be processed. See the docs at http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#input-sources

Comment: Hello,I have tried but throwing error.. can you please help ...  val csvDF = spark.readStream.option("sep", ",").schema(userSchema).csv("file:///home/sas/testdelta")   csvDF.writeStream.foreachBatch { (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
  batchDF.show
}.start()    <console>:56: error: value foreachBatch is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
       csvDF.writeStream.foreachBatch { (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>

Comment: @BigD What Spark version do you use? `foreachBatch` is available as of 2.4.0. Use `foreach` instead.

Comment: i am using spark  2.3.0.. i tried both.. in my example csvDF is dataframe.. how can i insert that to hive using foreach.. that is my issue

Comment: @BigD Create a repo at github and share the link with the code you have so far. Ping me offline for code review.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54021043/how-to-use-foreachrdd-in-spark-streaming-for-csv-files/54021500#54021500

Comment: We're talking Spark Structured Streaming here while you're using Spark Streaming in the link above. They're hugely different.

Comment: i really not aware about how spark structured streaming ingesting data to HIVE. that is the reason i have tried with spark streaming ..there also am failing.. would you be able to give some working examples to ingest data to hive ?

Comment: am not able to write results to hdfs location... after aggregating data on spark structured streaming ... can you please tell how to use foreach method to achieve my goal

Comment: Use gist.github.com to post the entire code and show the inputs.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski your code will never compile in Spark 2.4.0. Did you ever test it?

Comment: Hi, is it possible to use checkpointing with the foreachBatch? Let's say that something fails, can I recover the data?

Comment: @RonF Can you ask a separate question so it gets proper attention of the Spark community? Merci.

Comment: Hi @JacekLaskowski , Could you please give any valid examples for the foreachBatch batch sink. I have a use case to write some raw data to Hive tables in real time(structured streaming - source kafka)

Answer (score 2):

On HDP 3.1 with Spark 2.3.2 and Hive 3.1.0 we have used Hortonwork's *spark-llap* library to write structured streaming DataFrame from Spark to Hive. On [GitHub](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/spark-llap) you will find some documentation on its usage.

The required library hive-warehouse-connector-assembly-1.0.0.3.1.0.0-78.jar is available on [Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.hortonworks.hive/hive-warehouse-connector_2.11/1.0.0.3.1.0.0-78) and needs to be passed on in the `spark-submit` command. There are many more recent versions of that library, although I haven't had the chance to test them.

*After* creating the Hive table manually (e.g. through beeline/Hive shell) you could apply the following code:

```scala
import com.hortonworks.hwc.HiveWarehouseSession

val csvDF = spark.readStream.[...].load()

val query = csvDF.writeStream
  .format(HiveWarehouseSession.STREAM_TO_STREAM)
  .option("database", "database_name")
  .option("table", "table_name")
  .option("metastoreUri", spark.conf.get("spark.datasource.hive.warehouse.metastoreUri"))
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/path/to/checkpoint/dir")
  .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone actually tried the code from Jacek Laskowski he knows that it does not really compile in Spark 2.4.0 (check my [gist](https://gist.github.com/bepcyc/71ef754c0ca4a41af0cbb951f1c50c79) tested on AWS EMR 5.20.0 and vanilla Spark). So I guess that was his idea of how it should work in some future Spark version.
The real code is:

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset

scala> sq.writeStream.foreachBatch((batchDs: Dataset[_], batchId: Long) => batchDs.show).start
res0: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery = 
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingQueryWrapper@5ebc0bf5
```

Comment: but am using spark 2.3.0.. can you provide how to use foreach in 2.3.0