# How to use foreachRDD in legacy Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am getting exception while using foreachRDD for my CSV data processing. Here is my code

```
  case class Person(name: String, age: Long)
  val conf = new SparkConf()
  conf.setMaster("local[*]")
  conf.setAppName("CassandraExample").set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
  val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(10))
  val smDstream=ssc.textFileStream("file:///home/sa/testFiles")

  smDstream.foreachRDD((rdd,time) => {
  val peopleDF = rdd.map(_.split(",")).map(attributes => 
  Person(attributes(0), attributes(1).trim.toInt)).toDF()
  peopleDF.createOrReplaceTempView("people")
  val teenagersDF = spark.sql("insert into table devDB.stam SELECT name, age 
  FROM people WHERE age BETWEEN 13 AND 29")
  //teenagersDF.show  
    })
  ssc.checkpoint("hdfs://go/hive/warehouse/devDB.db")
  ssc.start()
```

i am getting following error
java.io.NotSerializableException: DStream checkpointing has been enabled but the DStreams with their functions are not serializable
org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
Serialization stack:
        - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext, value: org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext@1263422a)
        - field (class: $iw, name: ssc, type: class org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext)

please help

Comment: I will look tomorrow properly, but I noted you were looking at Structured Streaming before.

Comment: Anything is fine for me... But need to insert data into hive using insert into operation

Comment: My understanding was saving to paths, and that that was not possible. I wkll recheck.

Comment: Saving to hdfs location is possible and we can create hive table on top of that... But my query is how to insert directly to hive...its possible in spark. But not sure how to do it in spark streaming or structured one...

Comment: Cannot do in structured; may be 2.4. You sse the serialization error.

Comment: What about normal streaming ? That also fine for me

Comment: As I am in between assignments, I spent time on this. It is clear to me the simple examples are misleading and I see it in your case as well. Checkpointing and Serialization errors, etc. Painful legacy. writeStream is far better for file writing, move on is my advice. Success.

Comment: Do u have any examples

Comment: The documentation and such apoear ok. But some examples do not work. The spark guides are fine. I am closing. The other answer is not correct either.

Comment: I do not seem to be able to get the Person Case Class to work, it's legacy but I just do not like giving up!

Comment: I think I solved it, will post but expect credits!

Comment: Sure .. Can you please provide the example

Comment: But it is legacy so it is more academic, will post shortly

Comment: Posted an updated answer.

Comment: Not an area everyone understands, anyway, a few learnsome points here (for you) and me.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help....really appreciate your effort....

Comment: no problem, cheers

Comment: sorry to ask... will you be able to provide any inputs on following questions on structured streaming ..         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53963727/how-to-insert-spark-structured-streaming-dataframe-to-hive-external-table-locati

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question does not really make sense anymore in that **dStreams are being deprecated / abandoned.**

There a few things to consider in the code, what the exact question is therefore hard to glean. That said, I had to ponder as well as I am not a Serialization expert.

You can find a few posts of some trying to write to Hive table directly as opposed to a path, in my answer I use an approach but you can use your approach of Spark SQL to write for a TempView, that is all possible.

I simulated input from a QueueStream, so I need no split to be applied. You can adapt this to your own situation if you follow the same "global" approach. I elected to write to a parquet file that gets created if needed. You can create your tempView and then use spark.sql as per your initial approach.

> The Output Operations on DStreams are:
>
> - print()
> - saveAsTextFiles(prefix, [suffix])
> - saveAsObjectFiles(prefix, [suffix])
> - saveAsHadoopFiles(prefix, [suffix])
> - foreachRDD(func)
>
> **foreachRDD**
>
> The most generic output operator that applies a function, func, to
>   each RDD generated from the stream. This function should push the data
>   in each RDD to an **external** system, such as saving the RDD to files, or
>   writing it over the network to a database. Note that the function func
>   is executed in the driver process running the streaming application,
>   and will usually have RDD actions in it that will force the
>   computation of the streaming RDDs.
>
> It states saving to files, but it can do what you want via foreachRDD, albeit I
>   assumed the idea was to external systems. Saving to files is quicker
>   in my view as opposed to going through steps to write a table
>   directly. You want to offload data asap with Streaming as volumes are typically high.

**Two steps:**

> In a separate class to the Streaming Class - run under Spark 2.4:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
```

> Then the Streaming logic you need to apply - you may need some imports
>   that I have in my notebook otherwise as I ran this under DataBricks:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import scala.collection.mutable
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode

val spark = SparkSession
           .builder
           .master("local[4]")
           .config("spark.driver.cores", 2)
           .appName("forEachRDD")
           .getOrCreate()

val sc = spark.sparkContext
val ssc = new StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext, Seconds(1)) 

val rddQueue = new mutable.Queue[RDD[List[(String, Int)]]]()
val QS = ssc.queueStream(rddQueue) 

QS.foreachRDD(q => {
   if(!q.isEmpty) {   
      val q_flatMap = q.flatMap{x=>x}
      val q_withPerson = q_flatMap.map(field => Person(field._1, field._2))
      val df = q_withPerson.toDF()      

      df.write
        .format("parquet")
        .mode(SaveMode.Append)
        .saveAsTable("SO_Quest_BigD")
   }
 }
)

ssc.start()
for (c <- List(List(("Fred",53), ("John",22), ("Mary",76)), List(("Bob",54), ("Johnny",92), ("Margaret",15)), List(("Alfred",21), ("Patsy",34), ("Sylvester",7)) )) {
   rddQueue += ssc.sparkContext.parallelize(List(c))
} 
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Where did u write the code to insert data into  hive? Instead of path